# Java NativeCall Library Return Data Types

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am currently trying to access DBFs using NTX indexes from Java. I have a copy of the Artemis engine (now ApolloDB) from many years ago which works to do this in VB6. It uses 3 DLLs principally SDE32.DLL.

I have successfully accessed many of the functions in these DLLs using NativeCall

`public static VoidCall sx_Zap = new VoidCall("SDE32", "sx_Zap");`
`public static IntCall sx_Use = new IntCall("SDE32", "sx_Use");`

```
intFile = sx_Use.executeCall(fileName);
        if (intFile == 0){
            if (JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Could not open:" + fileName + "\nRetry?", "Failed to open DBF", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                return;
            }else{
                sx_Zap.executeCall();
            }
        }
```

That code will quite happily open and zap the database so I know I am on the right track. Note that I used an IntCall when I wanted to return an integer and a VoidCall when I wanted to return nothing.

The problem I have found is that some of the functions like some of the data access functions return Strings e.g. the function declaration in VB6 for the sx_GetString function which gets a string field from the current record.
`Declare Function sx_GetString Lib "sde32.dll" (ByVal cpFieldName As String) As String`

How do I get this information into Java? There only seems to be int (and boolean) and void return types, how can I get String, double and long types back?

Using JNA I can access doubles and longs it seems but when I try a string return type I get Execution protection violation and Java crashes out.

JNA Example:

```
public interface SDE32 extends Library {
   public String sx_GetString(String cpFieldName);
   public Double sx_GetDouble(String cpFieldName);
   public Long sx_GetLong(String cpFieldName);
```

}

```
JNADBF.SDE32 sde = (JNADBF.SDE32) Native.loadLibrary("SDE32", JNADBF.SDE32.class);
    System.out.println(sde.sx_GetString("TILLNAME"));
    System.out.println(sde.sx_GetDouble("SELLPRICE"));
```

JNA Error:

`Execution protection violation`

`#`

`# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:`

`#`

`#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=11104, tid=11060`

So how can I get these return types? Especially String.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest returning a Pointer first (rather than a String), then use the various Pointer methods to examine the memory to which it points.  Once you understand what the function is returning, you can figure out how to make JNA recover the data properly (either automatically or explicitly).

**EDIT**

```
public interface SDE32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   public Pointer sx_GetString(String cpFieldName); // don't use String just yet
   public double sx_GetDouble(String cpFieldName);
   // Don't use Java "long" unless you want a 64-bit integer
   // On windows, native "int" and "long" are both 32 bits
   public NativeLong sx_GetLong(String cpFieldName);
}
```

**EDIT**
Referring to the [pascal header files](http://read.pudn.com/downloads92/sourcecode/others/360042/apollovcl61/SDE60.pas__.htm) for a more recent version, you should be using the Java type `short` for `smallInt` and `WordBool`, and `int` for `Long`.  However, switching to these types does not provide a complete fix (it will reduce stack corruption - you will have been "opening" the DB with the wrong flags).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to return a Pointer either, I get the same error. Could you perhaps provide an example line for me to try so I can confirm that I am not just doing it wrong?

Comment: Try extending StdCallLibrary instead of Library.  VB typically requires the called DLL to use the stdcall calling convention (or at least uses that by default); to use stdcall in JNA you need to implement the StdCallLibrary interface.

Comment: Nope, still exactly the same error, I could email you the DLL or upload it to the internet or something; then you can see the error in person if you like.

Comment: Double check your Pointer-returning results.  Don't use String, because for all you know it's returning a `BSTR`, a pascal string, or some other format other than a C string.

Comment: Returning a pointer gives the same error as returning a string (I copied in your example code). Its the actual returning bit that fails I think. I am retrieving the value by: Pointer ptr = sde.sx_GetString("TILLNAME");

Comment: A copy of the DLL is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/59308019/SDE.zip you have to use these functions in order to get access to the database sx_Use(PathToDBF, Alias, 0, 1) then sx_SetTranslate(Boolean.TRUE) then sx_GoTop() then sx_GetString("FIELDNAME")

Comment: This would be a lot easier if I had the code for the DLL or even knew what language it was written in.

Comment: I take it you don't have any NativeCall code that accesses Strings?

Comment: Can you include a sample database?  I don't imagine I'd get much success reading from /dev/null...

Comment: This link (http://read.pudn.com/downloads92/sourcecode/others/360042/apollovcl61/SDE60.pas__.htm), perhaps referring to a newer release, indicates that the DLL uses the stdcall calling convention.

Comment: Will read that, in the mean time - Sample database: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/59308019/STHEAD.DBF

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16332/discussion-between-feldoh-and-technomage)